# How do you simplify .str.contains code with multiple contains variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

I am using the Series.str.contains() function to find if a value in a dictionary is contained in a string from a specific column. My code works, but I am trying to simplify it.

I tried using a for loop to go through the values in a list. My attempt is down below.

```
 total_joined_list=[joined_groc_lst,joined_util_lst]

 for i in range(len(total_joined_list)):



groc_amount,util_amount=abs(round(df.loc[df['Description'].str.contains('\b'+i+'\b',na=False),'Amount'].sum(),2))
```

Here is the current working code.

```
 joined_groc_lst = '|'.join(expenses_dict['Groceries'])
 joined_util_lst = '|'.join(expenses_dict['Utilities'])



groc_amount=abs(round(df.loc[df['Description'].str.contains('\b'+joint_groc_lst+'\b',na=False),
                    'Amount'].sum(),2))
 util_amount=abs(round(df.loc[df['Description'].str.contains('\b'+joint_util_lst+'\b',na=False),
                    'Amount'].sum(),2))
```

I expect my function to create two variables; groc_amount and util_amount, and I would be able to print my results. I got this error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" and then added str() to the i in my for loop and get the following error "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object"

Comment: can you provide some values in `joined_groc_lst` and `joined_util_lst`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
total_joined_list=[joined_groc_lst,joined_util_lst]

groc_amount, util_amount = (abs(round(df.loc[df['Description'].str.contains(f'\b{e}\b',na=False),'Amount'].sum(),2))  for e in total_joined_list)
```

I have change your [forloop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) into a generator that allow unpacking data in order to get each items in the list.

Comment: It gives me a type error "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object"

Comment: Ok I understand your mistake, I will edit the answer

Comment: @NickBosio is it better?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that ! Feel free to accept my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers